# Python script to batch-rename .WAV files in a directory, based on audio length

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-rename, batch-rename

I'm writing a Python Script that renames a bunch of .WAV files in a directory, and renames them, add the length of the audio file to the beginning of the file name.

What I got so far now is:

```
import wave
import contextlib
import os


for file_name in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if file_name.endswith(".wav") or file_name.endswith(".aiff"):
        with contextlib.closing(wave.open(file_name, 'r')) as f:
            frames = f.getnframes()
            rate = f.getframerate()
            duration = frames / float(rate)
            duration = int(duration)
            duration = str(duration)
            new_file_name = duration + " " + file_name
            print(file_name)
            os.rename(file_name, new_file_name)
    else:
        continue
```

But I got this error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'TEMFX01-RisingLong001.wav' -> '15 TEMFX01-RisingLong001.wav'
```

How can I make the process stop using it so I can rename it?

Thanks!

EDIT: Really silly, just needed to add f.close() before print(file_name).

Not sure if I should delete this topic or answer my own question?

Comment: unrelated: (1) use `os.listdir()` instead of `os.listdir(os.getcwd())`. (2) use `filename.endswith((".wav", ".aiff"))` instead of `file_name.endswith(".wav") or file_name.endswith(".aiff")` (you probably want `fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, '*.wav') or fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, '*.aiff')` in a portable code, to ignore the case on Windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close the wave before renaming.

```
import wave
import contextlib
import os


for file_name in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if file_name.endswith(".wav") or file_name.endswith(".aiff"):
        with contextlib.closing(wave.open(file_name, 'r')) as f:
            frames = f.getnframes()
            rate = f.getframerate()
            duration = frames / float(rate)
            duration = int(duration)
            duration = str(duration)
            new_file_name = duration + " " + file_name
            print(file_name)
            wave.close()
            os.rename(file_name, new_file_name)
    else:
```

Comment: `wave.close()` is redundant if `with`-statement is used. Unindent `os.rename()` (and replace it with `os.replace()` in case some other program has opened the file).

Answer (score 0):

```
import wave
import contextlib
import os
count = 0

for file_name in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if file_name.endswith(".wav") or file_name.endswith(".aiff"):
        count += 1
        with contextlib.closing(wave.open(file_name, 'r')) as f:
            frames = f.getnframes()
            rate = f.getframerate()
            duration = frames / float(rate)
            duration = int(duration)
            duration = str(duration)
            new_file_name = "audio" + str(count) + '.wav'
            print(file_name)
        os.rename(file_name, new_file_name)
    else:
        continue
```

***This code will resolve the issue***